# Initialize swiper

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I am trying to initialize my Swiper container after I have made some API calls. When I do this, however,I get the error:

> Property 'swiper' does not exist on type Element.

Here is the link to the Swiper API: [Swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/api/)

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.spinner.show().then( async () => {
    this.data.currentProgress.subscribe(progress => this.progress = progress);
    await this.eventService.fetchEvents();
    }).then(async () => {
      const mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;
      mySwiper.init();
    }).then(() => {
      this.spinner.hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
const mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;
```

you should try this:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   speed: 400,
   spaceBetween: 100
});
```

This will initialize your swiper.

Question 2:  Add this in index.html :

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
...
```

You have a lot of possibilities to include this. See https://swiperjs.com/get-started/

Comment: How would I import Swiper?

Comment: I am importing it in the .component.ts file. I tried ```import { SwiperModule, SwiperConfigInterface } from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';``` How would I instantiate Swiper from Swipermodule